# Problem when trying to use aireplay-ng and mdk3 with airgeddon

Tags: networking, wireless, security, aircrack-ng, pentesting

When i was trying out evil twin access point attack on my network using airgeddon everything went smoothly except when my fake ap is up airgeddon isn't able to do deauthentication attack so i tried doing deauthentication attack manually using aireplay-ng but it doesn't work so i tried mdk3 it's showing me this
Command - mdk3 wlp2s0 d -c 2

"ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Device or resource busy

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211, ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead. Make sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlp2s0 <#>'

Sysfs injection support was not found either."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvBOt.png)

I am using Realtek semiconductor wifi 802.11pce it can do both monitor mode and packet injection functions

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running, as that will help in troubleshooting your issue. Thanks